# Find the y-values(s) where $x^2 - y^2 = 3x + 3y + 4$ has vertical tangents

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Find the y-values(s) where $x^2 - y^2 = 3x + 3y + 4$ has vertical tangents

ok, so this is me trying to prove my teacher is wrong....she says that the points are -1,0,1 and I believe this to be incorrect but I'm having issues with deriving the function.

Comment: “Not possible”? I’ve seen teachers make worse mistakes than this. More things are possible than you may realize, Mr. Jagy. Teachers don’t deserve so much benefit of the doubt just for being teachers. I say this, as a math teacher, who expects no benefit if the doubt in such situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vertical tangents to a curve occur when 
$$
\frac{dx}{dy}=0
$$
Now for your curve, we implicitly differentiate to find
$$
2x\frac{dx}{dy}-2y=3\frac{dx}{dy}+3\implies \frac{dx}{dy}(2x-3)=3+2y\\
\implies \frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{3+2y}{2x-3}
$$
if this is to vanish, then $3=-2y\implies y=-3/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Applying $\frac{d}{dx}$ to the equation, we get:

$$2x-2yy'=3+3y'$$

and then isolating $y'$, we get:

$$y'=\frac{2x-3}{3+2y}.$$

It looks like the derivative should be undefined precisely when $y=-\frac32$

A glance at [the graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=implicit+plot+x%5E2-y%5E2%3D3x%2B3y%2B4) seems to confirm this.

---

Another approach would be to complete the squares and see this equation for what it really is:

$$x^2-3x+\frac94-(y^2+3y+\frac94)=4$$

or:

$$\frac{\left(x-\frac32\right)^2}{2^2}-\frac{\left(y+\frac32\right)^2}{2^2}=1.$$

It's a hyperbola with left/right branches, centered at $\left(\frac32,-\frac32\right)$. There's nothing special going on at $y=-1,0,1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The equation of any vertical tangent can be set to $$x=k$$

Now replace this value of $x,$ in the equation of the hyperbola to form a quadratic equation in $y$ whose  roots represent the ordinate of the intersection

Now for tangency, both ordinates should coincide.

Can you take it from here?